My hot tub is causing an electrical shock when I place one finger inside the water
Its a used hot tub bought from a previous owner.  It worked well when first installed, after a few uses the cord became too hot to touch and then I noticed an electric current in the water. I emptied the tub, replaced the cord with a brand new one, and now I notice that you can feel the electric current in the water if you place just 1 finger in the water while standing on the outside of the tub itself. If you were to place 2 fingers in the water, you can not sense an electric current at all.

Turn it off and get it thoroughly checked by a competent certified electrician.

That is why a GFCI protection is required near water.  Unplug/disconnect/turn off that breaker and have it checked out/replaced.

looking for causes to the issue..... I have already unplugged from the gfci power source

A cord too hot to touch usually means a bad connection or high current draw.  A high current draw leads to heat and can damage electric insulation on wires.  Possible at less than 5% it might be static electricity, but is not something I want to bet the farm on.  You want an expert with the right testing equipment to check it out before using again.

GFCI!!!!!
Can't emphasize this enough. You MUST have any water-related item such as a hot tub on a GFCI-protected circuit. That typically means a receptacle that has "TEST" and "RESET" buttons on it, but sometimes it is a circuit breaker with GFCI included or a "deadfront" which is basically a thing that is the same size as a GFCI/receptacle but has the TEST/RESET buttons without the actual plug-in part.
If this hot tub is plugged into a GFCI/receptacle, test it with TEST/RESET and if it does not work properly then it must be replaced.
If this hot tub is plugged in any place else, you must make sure it is actually GFCI protected. Labels don't guarantee it - wiring can sometimes be messed up or bypassed. If you are not sure, test using a GFCI tester such as this Klein from Amazon:

If it turns out the receptacle is not properly GFCI protected, that's the first thing to fix. If it is GFCI protected then you should not be able to feel anything "electrical" when touching the water. If you still feel something then there may be something seriously wrong and I would have it checked by a professional before using it.
It is possible to have a very low-level ground fault that isn't quite enough to trip the GFCI and that if the ground fault was a little bigger that it would trip the GFCI. But I'd really be concerned as it doesn't make much (on the order of 6 milliamps) to trip a GFCI.
If the hot tub trips the GFCI and didn't before because the GFCI was broken or not properly wired, then you have a ground fault in the hot tub that needs to be fixed. If the hot tub still doesn't trip the GFCI then you still need to get the hot tub checked and possibly fixed but at least you will have some degree of safety in place and be ready even if the result is getting a new hot tub.
Hot Cord
"cord became too hot to touch" is very unusual. A cord becomes hot if the conductors are smaller than they should be or there is more current flowing than designed. The problem could be the cord itself. But it could also be a faulty heating element or some other problem that is causing the hot tub to draw much more current than it is supposed to. In addition, if the cord is getting hot then any control circuits are likely to be getting hot as well, and those can be damaged in ways that are much harder to fix than a cord replacement.

Overall, I think this adds up to "if you have to ask us, bite the bullet and call a pro." Which would be my advice.

Thank you much for the thorough response.

Lets say I used an extension cord originally, thats when the cord became too hot to touch and fused itself together.  I ordered a brand new cord and replaced the other, this time I had a cord long enough to reach the outside outlet.  This cord is connected to a GFCI outlet on the outside of the house which leads to a  20 amp in the inside fuse box.  There is 2 outlets outside of the house and a patio light that is the only thing drawing power from the fuse box itself.  The new cord didnt get too hot to touch, but instead tripped the cord itself before tripping the outlet and the fuse box.

Im just confused as to why there is a small current that you can feel with just 1 finger, and you cant feel it with 2 fingers.

I also just replaced the Heating element with a brand new one, still getting the electric shock feeling with just one finger...

What do you mean by "tripped the cord itself"?

The cheap extension cords are 16 gauge and should never be used for something that heats and/or needs most of a 15 or 20 amp circuit.  You want at least a 12 gauge extension for those uses.  The length is another concern, the shortest needed is the best.

The new power cord that I installed (bought for the use of hot tubs) has its own test/reset box on the cord itself....That tripped last night and now will no longer work, but when it was working, the same current feel that I was getting with one finger dipped into the water was still present. So I drained and hooked up a new Heating element as well as a new cord today.... Same result.

A ground fault can come from anywhere - controls, thermostat, etc
